# Azure DevOps : variable carrying the source code branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm somewhat confused as to what goes in Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName. When you run manually a YAML pipeline those predefined variables end up tracking the branch for the pipeline's definition itself, not the source code branch that is being checked out. I suppose since those variables need to be set when a pipeline is started, it would not be possible to have any one predefined variable return the checked out source code branch(es).

Comment: I read through this piece of text twice, and I (so personally) could not follow what you're saying. The docs seem pretty clear on these variables: `The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for.` so i'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Hi there, is there any update for this issue?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I started writing my yaml pipelines in an empty dedicated branch, a branch not containing the source code the pipeline works on and a few not so obvious (for me) things emerged. If starting such a yaml pipeline manually the Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName really return the branch containing the pipelines itself (the triggering branch) as the pipeline could really really be checking out any other repo/branch. To me this was not so obvious/expected.

Answer (score 1):

> When you run manually a YAML pipeline those predefined variables end
> up tracking the branch for the pipeline's definition itself, not the
> source code branch that is being checked out.

As stated in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services): `Build.SourceBranch` represents the branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for and `Build.SourceBranchName` is the name of the branch in the triggering repo the build was queued for.

These two variables are only used to track the triggering repo, they have nothing to do with source branches that are checked out. When **manually** running YAML pipeline, these variables only represent the branch selected here:

[image]

> I suppose since those variables need to be set when a pipeline is
> started, it would not be possible to have any one predefined variable
> return the checked out source code branch(es).

We don't have predefined variables for checked out branches. For pipelines that [check out multiple repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) with different branched, such variable(not supported) would have to contain more than
one branch names like "master:RepoA dev:RepoB ...".

**Possible workaround:**

Here's my working script for YAML pipeline that checks out self repo(`Test` repo) and another two repos(`Agile` repo and `RepoB` repo):

```
pool:
  VmImage: "windows-latest"

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoA
    type: git
    name: Agile
    ref: Test2.0
    trigger: 
    - Test2.0
  - repository: RepoB
    type: git
    name: RepoB
    ref: main
    trigger: 
    - main
    - dev
  
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: RepoA
- checkout: RepoB

- script: echo branch:$(Build.SourceBranch) from repo:$(Build.Repository.Name).
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script in master'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      if ("$(Build.Repository.Name)" -eq "Test") {
          $BranchOfYamlRepo = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
          $BranchOfRepoA = "Test2.0"
          $BranchOfRepoB = "main"
      }elseif ("$(Build.Repository.Name)" -eq "Agile") {
          $BranchOfYamlRepo = "main"
          $BranchOfRepoA = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
          $BranchOfRepoB = "main"
      }else {
          $BranchOfYamlRepo = "main"
          $BranchOfRepoA = "Test2.0"
          $BranchOfRepoB = "$(Build.SourceBranchName)"
      }
      Write-Host "$BranchOfYamlRepo,$BranchOfRepoA,$BranchOfRepoB"
```

Comment: Yes, I realize perfectly that for pipelines checking out multiple repositories/branches you'd need to append multiple repo/branch names into the predefined variable that returns the repo(s)/branch(es) the pipeline is working on.

Comment: @lance is there any way to manually define the triggering repo when you manually trigger the pipeline? It seems crazy that I can set all kinds of triggers in my YAML so as to correctly populate `Build.SourceBranch`, `Build.Repository.Name` for use in my pipeline, but then make it impossible for me to choose which repo and branch I want as my trigger when running manually. It seems to be hard coded as "the repo this YAML file is on is the triggering repo, and you can't change it"

Answer (score 0):

When you manually trigger a YAML pipeline, by default the pipeline will run on the default branch (master or main), if the YAML file also is existing on the default branch. So the source branch will be set as the default branch by default.

However, when you manually trigger the pipeline, you can specify the pipeline runs on another branch or a tag, and this also will set the source branch as the branch or tag you specify.

[image]

Comment: The branch selection you are showing is really only selecting the branch for the pipeline definition itself. In fact, if you select a branch where the pipeline is not present you'll get a  "Encountered error(s): Could not find valid pipeline YAML file for this branch/tag" error.